# Excel Chart - Input changes after running VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a chart that alters inputs after I run my code.

```
Sub copy_values_for_chart()
    With Worksheets("Working")
        'clear chart consolidated data
        LastRow = FindLastRow("Working")
        .Range("Y4:AE" & LastRow).Clear

        LastRow = FindLastRow("Working")

        'copy Eolus T-1 data
        .Range("Q4:W4").Copy
        .Range("Y4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        '.Range("Q3").Value = "Date"

        'calculate worst case P&L into col O
        For Line = 4 To LastRow
            If Range("O" & Line - 1).Value <> "" Then
                Range("o" & Line).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("J" & Line & ":" & "N" & Line))
            End If
        Next Line

        'append rage data
        .Range("I4:O" & LastRow).Copy
        .Range("Y5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        'append copy of static data
        .Range("A4 : G" & LastRow).Copy
        LastRow = FindLastRow("Working")
        .Range("Y" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


        'sort consolidated data by date asc
        LastRow = FindLastRow("Working")
        .Range("Y3:AE" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Worksheets("Working").Range("Y3"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

        'Application.CutCopyMode = False


    End With

    'update chart range data
    Set DataRange = Worksheets("Working").Range("Y3 : AE" & LastRow) 'Change last row to number to include. 

    Worksheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange

End Sub
```

Before I run, I have 6 Columns on the left side, and data on the right.

[image]

After I run my code I get 7 columns on the left including the date.
And where the old date was goes into a random format on the right.

[image]

Can anyone help me keep the way it should be after my code is ran?

Comment: What range do you use? Did you try to put in the value directly e.g. Source:=Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A1:F20")? Could be that "DataRange" contains 7 instead of 6 columns. To have an example chart and the datasheet might be helpfull as well. How did you create the chart before using the VBA code?

Comment: Hi Albin. I've edited my question with the part of my code that defines the Range of the chart. It looks like the range is correct, I do want Y to AE.  I believe I copied an existing chart over to create the chart, then kind of just updated the range and some other things.

Comment: If you only post part of you're code it will be difficult to find the problem within the code. You should post the complete code as well as the sheet with the data and the way you expect the code to behave. Then it will be possible to pinpoint the problem otherwise the problem can always be in within the part of the code you do not post.

Comment: Posting full code now.